# How to implement an IP access guard in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

Is there any way to implement a custom guard that allows access to users that match the stored ip. For this, each user has an ip associated in the database.

Comment: yes, yes there is

Comment: where, where can you tell in detail?

Answer (score 1):

With all guards you have access to the `request` via the `ExecutionContext` that each `canActivate` function uses. To get to the request you need to change the context to http, and then get the request. That can be done like this: `context.switchToHttp().getRequest()`. From there, ip is usually a top level property. Keep in mind, IPs are not static and are subject to change

Comment: The main problem is that I could not access the service from the guard and I cannot convert the module to global. I found another way to do it by using the service on a request from another guard that runs before and storing the ip in a collection for later comparison. Thank you.